# How to construct a Markov Chain of higher order given another Markov Chain

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Given a Markov Chain, I'm trying to construct a Markov Chain of a higher order. So, I'm given Markov Chain $\{ \xi_i \}$ such that $\xi_i \in E = \{0, 1, \dots, N \}$ (so it's finite) and

$$P(\xi_n = x_n | \xi_{n - 1} = x_{n - 1}, \xi_{n - 1} = x_{n - 1}, \dots, \xi_0 = x_0) = P(\xi_n = x_n | \xi_{n - 1} = x_{n - 1})$$

For any $x_n, \dots, x_0$ and $n \geq 1$. The transition matrix is time homogeneous and therefore $P(\xi_n = x_n | \xi_{n - 1} = x_{n - 1}) = p_{x_n x_{n - 1}}$.

An idea I'm trying to apply is basically the following: if I need a Markov Chain of order $m$ then I can make the transitional probability of my new process $\{ \eta_i \}$ so that it uniformly chooses some $t$ from $\{n - 1, n - 2, \dots, n - m\}$ (i.e. $t$ takes values of $n - 1, n - 2, \dots, n - m$ with the same probability) and then take the state from the step $t$, so that

$P(\eta_n = x_n | \eta_{n - 1} = x_{n - 1}, \dots, \eta_{n - m} = x_{n - m}, \dots, \eta_0 = x_0) = P(\eta_n = x_n | \eta_{n - 1} = x_{n - 1}, \dots, \eta_{n - m} = x_{n - m}) = p_{x_n x_t}$

Where $t$ is, as mentioned, sampled uniformly from past $m$ states. I was asked to write a rigorous proof that the resulting chain is indeed a Markov Chain with memory, but I'm unable to understand why my explanation that there is an explicit probability dependency only on the last $m$ states and therefore it is Markov Chain of higher order by construction is not accepted as it certainly seems valid to me.

Any ideas how to achieve the described goal?

Comment: The preferred way to write this is to show that a chain on an enlarged state space (in this case $E^m$) is Markov in the usual sense.

Comment: @Ian okay this makes sense, because as far as my understanding goes if $E^m$ chain happens to be Markov then the unwrapped one would be Markov Chain of order $m$. However, I'm still not sure how to prove the fact that $E^m$ would be the Markov Chain in a usual sense, could you please elaborate on that?